# Google directions API: JSON

Tags: php, api, directions

I am using the Google directions API in my web application, is there any way to shorten the direction description provided by Google?

I mean, for example,

```
Take the 2nd right.
Take the 2nd left toward ...
```

Can I shorten it? It's too long.

Can I make it just like this:

```
2nd right>2nd left>
```

Is there any way to modify the result? I am using PHP for developing the web application and the JSON format for displaying the API result.
edit:
The API result displays correctly. But I want to remove certain common words such as 'Take', 'The', 'at' etc
API result displaying part of my code:`if ($data->status === 'OK') {
    $route = $data->routes[0];
    foreach ($route->legs as $leg) {
        foreach ($leg->steps as $step) {
            echo $step->html_instructions . "<br>\n";`

Comment: Have you ever heard of any string functions?

Comment: @zerkms would you like to be more precise? I am a fresher to php

Comment: `strpos`, `substr`, `preg_match`, `preg_replace`. There is a finite phrases list used to describe directions - just parse them and format in a way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, hopefully it will work for you too...

```php
<?php
$test1 = 'Take the 2nd right.';
$test2 = 'Take the 2nd left toward the exit, then...';
$reg_find = '/Take the (.*?) (right|left).*/';
$reg_replace = '$1 $2';
$results = array(
    preg_replace($reg_find, $reg_replace, $test1),
    preg_replace($reg_find, $reg_replace, $test2)
);
echo implode('>', $results);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

For a more flexible solution, I have created this:

```php
<?php
$test1 = 'Take the 2nd right.';
$test2 = 'Take the 2nd left toward the exit, then ...';
$remove = '/( ?)(take|then|at|toward|the|exit|\.|,)( ?)/i';
$results = array(
    preg_replace($remove, '', $test1),
    preg_replace($remove, '', $test2)
);
echo implode('>', $results);
?>
```

Comment: that works fine..thank you @shaquin, pls see the edit in my question

Comment: The output is changing every time. What I want is just remove all those words specified above in my question from the result and display the rest using '>'